# Reference request: Riemann's paper on abelian functions

Tags: math-history, riemann-surfaces

I don't know if this is the right kind of question for here. 
But, can someone help me find an english translation (a link to a pdf would be nice) of: B. Riemann, "Theorie der Abelschen Funktionen", J. Reine Angew. Math., 54 (1857)

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>I found an English translation here: http://www.wlym.com/~jross/curvature/</strike>

---

Apparently the previous link I gave no longer exists, so here is another link to the same translation: [Part I](http://larouchepac.com/files/Riemann_AbelianFunctions1_0.pdf) and [Part II](http://larouchepac.com/files/Riemann_AbelianFunctions2_0.pdf) of the paper, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you will find it as a free pdf.

Other possibilities include purchasing an English translation of [Bernhard Riemann, Collected Papers](http://www.kendrickpress.com/Riemann.htm) which includes it.  Or you can double read the [original in German](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/AbelFn/AbelFn.pdf) and a [machine translation into English](http://translate.google.co.uk/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/AbelFn/AbelFn.pdf&act=url)

Comment: Thank you for these links!  Wow that machine translation is interesting.  When machines can make a readable and accurate translation of Riemann, I would say they will have at last come into their own.  Do you have a link to the actual original German paper, as opposed to a transcription of it?

Comment: You can try http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0054 starting at page 105:101

Comment: Henry: [Here](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=243919689_0054&PHYSID=phys120) is the link to the exact page. (Yes, it's a bit hard to link to specific articles at GDZ...) Alternatively, [DigiZeitschriften](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0054&DMDID=dmdlog17) is easier to link to.